# Python predefined variable named i?

Tags: python

I'm new to use Python 2.5.1, the following code will work:

sample3.py

```
num = 23

while (i !=num ):
    print 'bingo !'
    break;

===> result:  bingo !
```

but if I change i to j

sample3.py

```
num = 23

while (j !=num ):  <--- this is the only difference I changed i to j
    print 'bingo !'
    break;

===> result:  NameError: name 'j' is not defined
```

Anyone could tell me is it the varialbe name 'i' is predefined in Python?

Comment: first of all install python 2.7

Comment: Running your code I get `NameError: name 'i' is not defined` You have something else defined `i`

Comment: you really should post the real code

Comment: this is the real code... first sample works in Python 2.5.1..

Comment: That's not *all* the code, we are sure about that.

Comment: No, it is not the real code. You've missed something.

Comment: I know what's wrong there:

Any sample will not work if I run it first time.

I'm using IDLE as my Python editor, when I run other sample once which contains defined varialbe i, then the all open windows will be affected, it seems all editor window in IDLE shares the same defined name table!

Thanks a lot for everyone's quick response!

Answer (score 4):

NO, `i` is not predefined in python, you must have something else in your code before that is using `i`

Comment: I'm just confused that the first sample using i which is not defined but it works!

Comment: @Roger.z: No, it doesn't work. Start a new Python shell, paste the code there and see for yourself.

Comment: As @GabiPurcaru mentioned, check your imports also.

Comment: I'm using IDLE as my Python editor, that's the problem as I figure it out, thank you all for quick response!

Comment: If you restart IDLE and try it again with only this code, it will not work. The problem is that you had a definition left over from earlier. The interpreter session doesn't forget values unless you tell it do (with `del`). Please be sure to distinguish between running code in the interpreter, and running code from a .py file.